# How can I troubleshot a RabbitMQ ShutdownSignalException?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am running a bunch of tests on a project I'm maintaining that starts up a RabbitMQ queue.  As far as I can tell, I am not interacting with the RabbitMQ queue in any way.  But, periodically, I will get a `ShutdownSignalException` that seems to effect my test.  Here's an image of a breakpoint in the `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection#startShutdown` method:

[image]

How do I figure out what part of my code is triggering this exception?  Also, how can I be confident that my code does not use this queue?  Is there any special part of the RabbitMQ code I can put a breakpoint?

I am using Spring RabbitMQ version 1.3.5.RELEASE to configure my queue.  I don't have much knowledge of RabbitMQ so let me know if there's any other info I should provide.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection reset" generally means the socket was closed for some reason.

First step would be to look at the rabbitmq logs on the broker.

Because of the async nature of rabbitmq, the root cause might not be obvious on the calling thread but, generally, the reason property of the `ShutdownSignalEcxception` will generally describe the issue.

**EDIT**:

However, in this case, there is no `reason` because it's simply a socket reset detected in run...

```
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            _exceptionHandler.handleUnexpectedConnectionDriverException(AMQConnection.this,
                                                                        ex);
            shutdown(null, false, ex, true);
```

So you'll need to dig around more to find why the connection is reset; take a look in the broker's log to see if there are any clues.

Comment: But in this case if you click on the image, you can see that the field is null.  What would cause that?

Comment: Sorry; missed that - I added some more comments to my answer.